# Django Rest Framework - Filter nested one to many

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

### What I want to achieve:

I want a list of users with their respective missions, and filter on missions start date.

```
# Pseudo json
User 1
  - mission 1
  - mission 2
User 2
  - mission 1
  - mission 2
  - mission 3
```

### My data structure:

**Models**:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
  start = models.DateTimeField()
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="missions")
```

**Serializers**:

```
# Mission
class MissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model  = Mission
    fields = (
      'start',
      'end',
    )

# User
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  missions = MissionSerializer(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model  = MyUser
    fields = (
      'username',
      'missions',
    )
```

**Viewsets**:

```
# Filter
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  class Meta:
    model  = MyUser
    fields = {
      'missions__start': ['gte','lt']
    }

# Viewset
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  filter_backends  = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
  filter_class     = UserFilter
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  @list_route(methods=['get'])
  def listCalendar(self, request):
    prefetched_missions = Prefetch('missions', queryset=Mission.objects.all())
    objects_list = MyUser.objects.prefetch_related( prefetched_missions )
    objects_list = self.filter_queryset(objects_list)
    serializer   = UserSerializer(objects_list, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

### My Problem:

When calling this URL:

> /api/users/listCalendar/?start__gte=2015-06-29&start__lt=2015-08-10

The filter is ignored and I can't figure out a way to make it work.
I have the intuition that the problem is with `Mission.objects.all()` in the ViewSet that should probably be something like: `Mission.objects.filter(*But what here?*)`

Any help would be very much appreciated!

---

### Edit 1:

There is some progress! But still not working... As you suggested Mark Galloway i tried calling the following url:

> /api/users/listCalendar/?missions__start__gte=2015-06-29&missions__start__lt=2015-08-10

But this is the query that gets executed:

```
SELECT "app_myuser"."id", "app_myuser"."username"
FROM "app_myuser"
INNER JOIN "app_mission" ON ( "app_myuser"."id" = "app_mission"."user_id" )
INNER JOIN "app_mission" T4 ON ( "app_myuser"."id" = T4."user_id" )
WHERE ("app_mission"."start" >= '2015-07-06T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
AND T4."start" < '2015-07-12T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz)
ORDER BY "app_myuser"."username" ASC;
```

As you can see, there are 2 INNER JOIN instead of 1. For some reasons it takes the 2 filtered fields as if they were in separate tables. The result is that my results are dupplicated.

Comment: How about this? 
api/users/listCalendar/?missions__start__gte=2015-06-29&missions__start__lt=2015-08-10

Answer (score 4):

There are three things here

First, you're missing [the `DjangoFilterBackend`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) in your [`filter_backends` list](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#setting-filter-backends). This is what tells Django REST framework to look at the `filter_class` and apply the related filtering to the request, and without it your `filter_class` will be ignored (as you saw).

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_class = UserFilter
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Second, you're expecting to be able to use the `start` and `end` query parameters but are telling django-filter to look at the `missions__start` field in the `Meta.fields`. You can fix this by manually defining the fields on the `FilterSet` with your alias

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_gte = django_filter.DateTimeFilter(name='missions__start', lookup_type='gte', distinct=True)
    start_lte = django_filter.DateTimeFilter(name='missions__start', lookup_type='lte', distinct=True)

    end_gte = django_filter.DateTimeFilter(name='missions__end', lookup_type='gte', distinct=True)
    end_lte = django_filter.DateTimeFilter(missions__name='end', lookup_type='lte', distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model  = MyUser
        fields = ('start_gte', 'start_lte', 'end_gte', 'end_lte', )
```

Or by just referencing the query parameters will the full values (`missions__start_gte` instead of `start_gte`).

Third, because of how `INNER JOIN` queries work across multiple tables, you will receive duplicate values when doing a filter that affects multiple missions under a single user. You can fix this by using [the `distinct` argument](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#distinct) in your filters (as shown above) or adding `.distinct()` to the end of your filter calls in `filter_queryset`.

Comment: Top, I also forgot DjangoFilterBackend and kept wondering what I did wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

#### Given that you want to filter nested missions

I would suggest that you do this the other way around, and then handle
the rest client side. i.e.

**First** send a request for filtered missions, that reference the id of their user.
**Then** send a request for the referenced users i.e. "#id__in=1,2,3"
**...or** if you'll only ever have a small number of users: Send a request for all the user

That being said, I think you can also have your way if you want, by
applying the filters to the missions as well, by extending filter_queryset

#### Here is one approach to filtering nested missions

Note that if you don't want to filter the nested missions, you can simply
delete the filter_queryset method from the class.

```
class MissionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Mission
        fields = {
            'start': ['gte', 'lt'],
            'end': ['gte', 'lt'],
        }

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = {
            'start': ['gte', 'lt'],
            'end': ['gte', 'lt'],
        }

class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends  = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class     = UserFilter
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Get the original queryset:
        qs = super(UserViewset, self).get_queryset()

        # * Annotate:
        #     * start = the start date of the first mission
        #     * end = the end date of the last mission
        # * Make sure, we don't get duplicate values by adding .distinct()
        return qs.annotate(start=models.Min('missions__start'),
                           end=models.Max('missions__end')).distinct()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        # Get the original queryset:
        qs = super(UserViewset, self).filter_queryset(queryset)

        # Apply same filters to missions:
        mqs = MissionFilter(self.request.query_params,
                            queryset=Missions.objects.all()).qs
        # Notice: Since we "start", and "end" in the User queryset,
        #         we can apply the same filters to both querysets

        return qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('missions', queryset=mqs))
```

#### Here is another idea

This way you can use the same query parameters that you're already using.

```
class MissionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Mission
        fields = {
            'start': ['gte', 'lt'],
            'end': ['gte', 'lt'],
        }

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = {
            'missions__start': ['gte', 'lt'],
            'missions__end': ['gte', 'lt'],
        }

class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends  = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class     = UserFilter
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset         = MyUser.objects.all().distinct()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        # Get the original queryset:
        qs = super(UserViewset, self).filter_queryset(queryset)

        # Create a copy of the query_params:
        query_params = self.request.GET.copy()

        # Check if filtering of nested missions is requested:
        if query_params.pop('filter_missions', None) == None:
            return qs

        # Find and collect missions filters with 'missions__' removed:
        params = {k.split('__', 1)[1]: v
                  for k, v in query_params.items() if k.startswith('missions__')}

        # Create a Mission queryset with filters applied:
        mqs = MissionFilter(params, queryset=Missions.objects).qs.distinct()

        return qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('missions', queryset=mqs))
```

I haven't tested any of this, so it would be cool to get some feedback.

Comment: Ahh, wait... you only want the missions that fit within these dates listed, right? In that case this would not work.

Comment: I just added a filter_queryset method that would also take care of that scenario.

Comment: Completely building a custom filter that almost replaces the filterset is overkill here

Comment: It's only 12 lines of code added to filter_queryset. It's a bit of a hack, sure, but I really don't think that I deserve a down vote on this one.

Comment: I rewrote the example and added a new idea based on the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter_class is being ignored because you are not declaring the DjangoFilterBackend inside filter_backends.

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend)
  filter_class = UserFilter
```

Since you have an OrderingFilter but no ordering_fields, perhaps you put the wrong backend?

Comment: Hi, you're right, it couldn't work. But I added it and it still ignores the filters...

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you wnat is Mission.objects.filter(id=self.request.user), with this you will get all the missions for the current user

Comment: Hi, I want to filter on the missions start date. I edited the question so that it is more obvious.